# Async test with jest returning empty div

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

So i have this axios test and Im getting an empty div, not sure why.

test

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestAxios from '../test_axios.js';
import {act, render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitForElement} from '@testing-library/react';
import axiosMock from "axios";


afterEach(cleanup)

it('Async axios request works', async () => {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<TestAxios url={url} />);

  act(() => {
    axiosMock.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {title: 'some title'} })
         .then(console.log('ggg')) )
  })


  expect(getByText(/...Loading/i).textContent).toBe("...Loading")

  const resolvedSpan = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("title"));

  expect((resolvedSpan).textContent).toBe("some title");

  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);

 })
```

the component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const TestAxios = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(props.url)
      .then(res => setState(res.data))
  }, [])


  return (
  <div>
    <h1> Test Axios Request </h1>
      {state
        ? <p data-testid="title">{state.title}</p>
        : <p>...Loading</p>}
  </div>
  )
}


export default TestAxios;
```

the mock function

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }) )
};
```

so Im supposed to get a p element with some text but I get nothing. I have tried many different things bt cant seem to get it work not sure why its not working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out it turns out you have to call axios.mockresolved value before the rendering of the component, otherwise it will just use the value you provided as the default in your mock axios module.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestAxios from '../test_axios.js';
import {act, render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitForElement} from '@testing-library/react';
import axiosMock from "axios";


afterEach(cleanup)

it('Async axios request works', async () => {
  axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue({data: { title: 'some title' } })

  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  const { getByText, getByTestId, rerender } = render(<TestAxios url={url} />);

  expect(getByText(/...Loading/i).textContent).toBe("...Loading")

  const resolvedEl = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("title"));

  expect((resolvedEl).textContent).toBe("some title")

  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
 })
```